# Cannot resolve Func<T> with "Link All"

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, unity-container

The resolution throws an exception if I switch on 'Link All', otherwise it doesn't. Why is that?

```
c.RegisterType<A>();

c.Resolve<Func<A>>();
```

This works with "Link All"...

```
c.RegisterInstance<Func<A>>(() => new A());

c.Resolve<Func<A>>();
```

Being able to resolve a factory of a registered type is standard Unity functionality.

I'm using `Func` elsewhere so I don't think it's been stripped out.

Comment: Did you use Linking on Android?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker

Comment: This is regarding iOS.